# jQuery ui datepicker questions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am having two text fields From, To.Here i want to do many things with is two fields.

1. I want to **select next three days** on selected date.Which means,if I am selecting `jan 1,2012` in *From* field , then *To* field  should automatically select `jan 1,2,3 2012`.
2. While I am **hover** on `jan 1`, It should highlight `jan 1,2,3`
3. While I am **selecting** on `jan 1` it should it disable after **10 days** (after `jan 10` all dates should disabled)
4. Suppose I **disabled** `jan 2` means.While I am selecting `jan 1` tool tip message should say you can't select these dates.

Give me the reference idea which functions are used to do this.If you have example code for any of these please share.It will be very help full.

This is my setup

```
var dates = jQuery("#From,#To").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: excludeDates,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "m/d/y",
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate, inst) {
        var option = this.id == "From" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = jQuery(this).data("datepicker"),
            date = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || jQuery.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);

        var d = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay);
        var mydate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', d);





    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you have done so far?? create a fiddle first so that we can manipulate with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a complete answer but I've [**hacked something together**](http://jsfiddle.net/DwQvu/) which should hopefully get you started. It meets some of your requirements but the hover highlighting is not perfect (sometimes extra dates are left highlighted) and I'm not happy with all of the  JavaScript Date objects so there is probably some optimisation to be done. The code is included below:

#### HTML

```
From:<div id="fromDate"></div>
To:<div id="toDate"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
body {
    margin:10px 0 0 5px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:.8em;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-highlight a {
    background: #743620 none; /* a color that fits the widget theme */
    color: white; /* a color that is readeable with the color above */
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('#fromDate').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        // set range <selected, +10d> on toDate
        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var maxDate = new Date(minDate);
        maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 9);

        var plusOne = new Date(minDate);
        plusOne.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
        var plusTwo = new Date(minDate);
        plusTwo.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 2);
        var nowPlusThree = [minDate, plusOne, plusTwo];

        $('#toDate').datepicker('destroy').multiDatesPicker({minDate: minDate, maxDate:maxDate, 'addDates': nowPlusThree});

        $('#fromDate').off('hover', 'a');
    }
});

$('#toDate').datepicker();

$('#fromDate').on('hover', 'a', function() {
    var hoveredDate = new Date($('#fromDate .ui-datepicker-month').text() + ' ' + $(this).text() + ' ' + $('#fromDate .ui-datepicker-year').text());

    var plusOne = new Date(hoveredDate);
    plusOne.setDate(hoveredDate.getDate() + 1);
    var plusTwo = new Date(hoveredDate);
    plusTwo.setDate(hoveredDate.getDate() + 2);
    var nowPlusThree = [hoveredDate, plusOne, plusTwo];

    var existingDates = $('#toDate').multiDatesPicker('getDates');
    $('#toDate').multiDatesPicker('removeDates', existingDates);
    $('#toDate').multiDatesPicker({'addDates': nowPlusThree});
});
```

Note that the demo jsFiddle also includes a [jQueryUI Theme](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and the [Multiple Dates Picker plugin](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/) as advised by @diEcho

Answer (score 1):

hope this links would be helpful

[`multiple datepicker`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/multidatespickr/)

here is complete **[demo lists](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/)**

Comment: :i'm getting this error while using multiple date picker Error: uncaught exception: Conversion "function->string" not allowed on jQuery.multiDatesPicker