# datepicker range selection with highlighting and selection callbacks

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery UI to display an inline datepicker of 2 months and I would like to enable a range selection from **one day to another day** with an highlighting in between and also to "catch" the **from day** and the **to day** dates with some callbacks so I be able to insert them into some inputs.

This is my current code:

HTML:

```
 <div id="journey-calendar"></div>
```

Script:

```
    $('#journey-calendar').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: [2, 1],
        showOtherMonths: true,
        altField: '.begin-trip-date',
        altFormat: 'dd M yy', defaultDate: null
    });
```

I would appreciate any help or demo!

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8600224/430112) may give you idea

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this. I had 2 datepickers, one for a start date and one for an end date. I added a css class to set a background color for the dates in the range. Here is my code:

```
},
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
  var fromDate = new Date($(".lblDateFrom").text());
  var toDate = new Date($(".lblDateTo").text());     

  if (date >= fromDate && date <= toDate) {
    return [true, 'ui-individual-date', ''];
  }
  else {
    return [true, '', ''];
 }
},

//css class
.ui-individual-date {
background-color: #F2F5F7;
}
```